# ASP.NET - Viewstate Size

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Is there a reliable method for viewing the size of the viewstate on any given postback?

Comment: You want to view it on the server, or in the page on the client?

Comment: No Preference -  I just want to know how much extra junk is getting passed back and forth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Enable Trace in the web.config.
2. Browse the application http:////Trace.axd
3. In the "Control Tree" Section , sum up the ViewState Size and Control state Size of the controls.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend using FireFox addon called "Viewstate Size". Quick, simple and convenient.

[image]

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5956/

Comment: This is really usefull. Only drawback is that it's not currently compatible with Firefox 4 neither with Ajax calls (within UpdatePanels)

Comment: Works in Firefox 21. Haven't tested AJAX though.

Answer (score 6):

To view it in the page at the bottom of each request you can enable page level tracing like:

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

You can read more about this technique here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Trace could be overkill sometimes. You can add this javascript to the page see quickly see how the ViewState grows as you click around.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Viewstate is now ' + $('#__VIEWSTATE').val().length + ' bytes.');
</script>
```

Comment: I've put this in a little TamperMonkey script to keep an eye on it - could be helpful to others (while not being a full answer in itself): http://uber-rob.co.uk/2016/05/monitoring-viewstate-size/

Comment: I use the same jQuery technique above, but rather than code in an alert, I use the F12 tools console command line and simply type: '$("input[id=__VIEWSTATE][type=hidden]").val().length;' and hit enter.  Its a little more ad-hoc than coding in an alert especially if you don't have easy access to the source html.

Answer (score 4):

In Google Chrome you can use **[Chrome Viewstate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-viewstate/lidplipfigoldfaeaglmkkjphmdncama)** or **[Viewstate indicator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/viewstate-indicator/mhfgbepafobiainjedlonoanghiedllg)** modules

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Using Trace
- Using a browser plugin
- Adding code to your project for extracting the viewstate size

I found this article quite useful "[Determining an ASP.NET Page's View State Footprint](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/07/06/programmatically-determining-an-asp-net-page-s-view-state-footprint.aspx)" and it covers the options mentioned above.

However what I ended up doing when I needed to look at the viewstate size etc. of a application I was brought in to work on, was to use a tool called "[ASP.NET ViewState Helper](http://www.binaryfortress.com/aspnet-viewstate-helper/)". 
What I liked about that tool was that I could run it as a standalone executable, no installation of plugins required and no changing of the code required.

The drawback is that it only works for IE but in my case that was fine.